# Array returns bad values only first time

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, steamworks-api

So I'm working with Steamworks (leaderboards) and i have some strange issue. When i fire my function to get scores, from debugging i know that it works just fine.However my array after 1st function run always returns default values.After I fire function for the second time everything works perfectly fine. I tried to track down the issue however i failed.

Here is my whole code that i am using in this case:

Struct for stats

```
 USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
    struct FScorePackage
    {
        GENERATED_BODY()

            UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, Category = "Leaderboard")
            FString PlayerName = "working";

        UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, Category = "Leaderboard")
            int32 Rank = 0;

        UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, Category = "Leaderboard")
            int32 Score = 0;

    };
```

Function that sent request to the steam:
.h

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Steam|Leaderboard", meta = (Latent, LatentInfo = "LatentInfo", HidePin = "WorldContextObject", DefaultToSelf = "WorldContextObject"))
        TArray<FScorePackage> DownloadScoresAroundUser(UObject* WorldContextObject, int AboveUser, int BelowUser, struct FLatentActionInfo LatentInfo);
```

.cpp

```
TArray<FScorePackage> USteamLeaderboard::DownloadScoresAroundUser(UObject* WorldContextObject, int AboveUser, int BelowUser, struct FLatentActionInfo LatentInfo)
{
    if (!m_CurrentLeaderboard)
    {
        return Scores;
    }

    if (UWorld* World = GEngine->GetWorldFromContextObject(WorldContextObject))
    {
        FLatentActionManager& LatentActionManager = World->GetLatentActionManager();
        if (LatentActionManager.FindExistingAction<SteamLeaderboardLatentClass>(LatentInfo.CallbackTarget, LatentInfo.UUID) == NULL)
        {
            // load the specified leaderboard data around the current user
            SteamAPICall_t hSteamAPICall = SteamUserStats()->DownloadLeaderboardEntries(m_CurrentLeaderboard, k_ELeaderboardDataRequestGlobalAroundUser, -AboveUser, BelowUser);
            m_callResultDownloadScore.Set(hSteamAPICall, this,&USteamLeaderboard::OnDownloadScore);
            LatentActionManager.AddNewAction(LatentInfo.CallbackTarget, LatentInfo.UUID, new SteamLeaderboardLatentClassScores(LatentInfo));

            return Scores;
        }
        return Scores;
    }
    return Scores;
}
```

Now callback function from steam:
.h

```
void OnDownloadScore(LeaderboardScoresDownloaded_t *pResult, bool bIOFailure);
    CCallResult <USteamLeaderboard, LeaderboardScoresDownloaded_t> m_callResultDownloadScore;
```

.cpp

```
void USteamLeaderboard::OnDownloadScore(LeaderboardScoresDownloaded_t *pCallback, bool bIOFailure)
{
    if (!bIOFailure)
    {
        m_nLeaderboardEntries = __min(pCallback->m_cEntryCount, 30);

        for (int index = 0; index < m_nLeaderboardEntries; index++)
        {
            SteamUserStats()->GetDownloadedLeaderboardEntry(pCallback->m_hSteamLeaderboardEntries, index, &m_leaderboardEntries[index], NULL, 0);
        }
        TranslateEntries();
        scores = true;


    }
}
```

And finally function that write scores in Array:

.h

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCosmetic, Category = "Steam|Leaderboard")
         TArray<FScorePackage> TranslateEntries();
```

.cpp

```
    TArray<FScorePackage> USteamLeaderboard::TranslateEntries()
    {
FScorePackage ThisScore;
        Scores.Init(ThisScore, 30);

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            ThisScore.PlayerName = GetSteamName(m_leaderboardEntries[i].m_steamIDUser);
            ThisScore.Rank = m_leaderboardEntries[i].m_nGlobalRank;
            ThisScore.Score = m_leaderboardEntries[i].m_nScore;
            Arrayas[i] = ThisScore;
        }
        return Scores;

    }
```

Scores array is just static TArray Scores and scores=true is only for latent check to go on with functions after calling DownloadScoresAroundUser :)

My normal flow with this is:
1.I already have handle for leaderboard.
2.I'm calling DownloadScoresAroundUser.
3.Flow goes to latent which cannot proceed becouse of scores=false.
4.After i got callback from steam OnDownloadScore fires, giving me all needed info(checked if really and it does!).
5.Then i call TranslateEntries to get all scores with names and rank in Array.
6.Then I'm printing whole array (with break package in unreal) and get default values of my struct.
7.After i fire whole cycle again i get proper values.

If any further info is required let me know :)

Comment: OT probably, but why the repeating `return Scores;`? On in the end would suffice.

Comment: OT? I was repeating it becouse it was bool function before and always got error saying :not all paths return value. I should change translate entries to void i guess tho. Can this returns affect my code? I mean return goes out of function right?

Comment: All of the 3 return values are the same and the `return` statements are redundant. I don't know if that has any impact on your actual error (I even doubt so). Hence I said my comment is /OT regrding your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but it appears that you have a latency issue.  When you make the request to download the scores, this is a time consuming call that does not block.  You set up a callback that will be called when the scores are ready, then return the existing empty `Scores` object.

When you make your second call, enough time has passed for the scores to have download and `Scores` to be populated, so it returns some scores.

Note that you have a potential race condition, where `DownloadScoresAroundUser` can access (return) `Scores` while your callback is populating that vector.

Here's one possible solution.  Before the scores have completed loading, `DownloadScoresAroundUser` returns an empty Score (or possibly one indicating that scores are being loaded).  Once the scores have been loaded and `Scores` populated, it will return those.  Also, the callback (besides populating `Scores`) can in some fashion notify the caller(s) of `DownloadScoresAndUser` that new scores are available.  They can respond to that by calling in again to get the updated scores and refresh the display.

Comment: That last sentence is correct. Return fires first.Before even OnDownloadScores and all rest of the code! Do you know maybe any good way to fix that? Shall i just make another function that only returns array or is there a way to modify existing one?

Comment: @Avengar Post edited with details of a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Translateentries copy data from 0 to 30 but only "Callback->m_cEntryCount" are actually initialized. So if it < at 30, the data from "Callback->m_cEntryCount" to 30 may be wrong. Can you print out the value of this variable "in SteamLeaderboard::OnDownloadScore" ?

Comment: Numer fixing is not a problem atm becouse i have only 3 scores now for test purposes. Rest always is default.  And when i was printing, everything was just fine :/